# Heroku rails 4 application deployment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, web-deployment

Hi I am beginner for ROR deployment. I tried heroku deployment. But it's not working. I my gem file I have put following gems

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

group :production, :staging do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3"
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'byebug'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'bcrypt'
```

My database.yml looks like

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I am getting following error on heroku console:

```
    -----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies...
       Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
       Installing rake 10.4.2
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing json 1.8.3
       Installing minitest 5.7.0
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing activesupport 4.1.8
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing actionview 4.1.8
       Installing rack 1.5.5
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing actionpack 4.1.8
       Installing mime-types 2.6.1
       Installing mail 2.6.3
       Installing actionmailer 4.1.8
       Installing activemodel 4.1.8
       Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
       Installing activerecord 4.1.8
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.10
       Using bundler 1.9.7
       Installing columnize 0.9.0
       Installing byebug 5.0.0
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.8.0
       Installing execjs 2.5.2
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing railties 4.1.8
       Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing multi_json 1.11.2
       Installing jbuilder 2.3.1
       Installing jquery-rails 3.1.3
       Installing pg 0.18.2
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing sprockets 2.12.4
       Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.2
       Installing rails 4.1.8
       Installing rdoc 4.2.0
       Installing sass 3.2.19
       Installing sass-rails 4.0.5
       Installing sdoc 0.4.1
       Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
       Installing uglifier 2.7.1
       Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 44 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Bundle completed (52.02s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: Paths in SQLite3 database URLs of the form `sqlite3:///path` will be treated as absolute in Rails 4.2. Please switch to `sqlite3:dbname`. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/Rakefile:6)
       rake aborted!
       Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:190:in `rescue in spec'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:187:in `spec'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_7c327500f441bbe0f5ec1b5b2f7a306a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I am using windows os for the development.
I am not able to figure it out what is the error? Need some help. Thank you.

After Adding `rails_12factor` into gem file I am getting following error on heroku logs

```
    -----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies....
       Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
       Installing rake 10.4.2
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing json 1.8.3
       Installing minitest 5.7.0
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing activesupport 4.1.8
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing actionview 4.1.8
       Installing rack 1.5.5
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing actionpack 4.1.8
       Installing mime-types 2.6.1
       Installing mail 2.6.3
       Installing actionmailer 4.1.8
       Installing activemodel 4.1.8
       Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
       Installing activerecord 4.1.8
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.10
       Using bundler 1.9.7
       Installing columnize 0.9.0
       Installing byebug 5.0.0
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.8.0
       Installing execjs 2.5.2
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing railties 4.1.8
       Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing multi_json 1.11.2
       Installing jbuilder 2.3.1
       Installing jquery-rails 3.1.3
       Installing pg 0.18.2
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing sprockets 2.12.4
       Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.2
       Installing rails 4.1.8
       Installing rdoc 4.2.0
       Installing sass 3.2.19
       Installing sass-rails 4.0.5
       Installing sdoc 0.4.1
       Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
       Installing uglifier 2.7.1
       Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 44 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Bundle completed (57.99s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: Paths in SQLite3 database URLs of the form `sqlite3:///path` will be treated as absolute in Rails 4.2. Please switch to `sqlite3:dbname`. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/Rakefile:6)
       rake aborted!
       Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:190:in `rescue in spec'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:187:in `spec'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_0e966ea42527f491d64dc7a384ec85b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Its related to sqlite3.

Comment: The reason could be the ***db*** name with `.sqlite3` extension here `database: db/production.sqlite3`

Comment: @Pavan then what will be the extension?

Comment: Don't know whether it could be a problem, just a guess.

Comment: Open your `Gemfile.lock` and find the gem that has `sqlite3` as a dependency and remove it from your `Gemfile`. Once you’ve done this run `bundle install` and ensure that `sqlite3` no longer exists in your `Gemfile.lock`. More Info check this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Comment: What is `DATABASE_URL` env in Heroku set to ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following into your gemfile and then bundle:

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

This will hopefully resolve your problem.

Comment: In your production file you have this: `  database: db/production.sqlite3`. There should not be any SQLite3 within the Production aspect. This is why I remove SQLite3 completely from projects and use PG only for both. Hopefully this is the issue?

Comment: Then what should be the my db name in production environment

Comment: The issue don't seem to be related to `rails_12factor` gem.

Comment: You cannot use SQLite3 in production and yet it looks like you are? You have to use PG.